# While priting a div content it is taking space and blank pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to print a specific `<div>` with an `id` using `onclick()` function on a button and `window.print()` property on it.

For this, I wrote some `@media print` CSS.

It prints the `<div>` content but it takes a lot of spacing, causing blank pages. Here is my code:

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #printpage,
  #printpage * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #printpage {
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.print();">Print</button>

<div id="printpage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`visibility: hidden;` doesn't stop the element from taking up space on the page, it effectively makes it invisible but still take up space.

You may want to use `display: none;` which will also remove the space that the element takes up.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #888;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container div {
  height: 20px;
}

.vis {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.dis {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="vis"></div>
  Visibility
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="dis"></div>
  Display
</div>
```

Comment: I want to print only the content inside div id printpage but if i will use display hidden on body then it will hide all content including div id printpage , I know visibility take spaces but what is the solution of it

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the height and width of the printpage that has fixed position

```
@media print {
 body{ margin: 0; padding: 0 }
 #printpage {
   min-height: 100vh; margin: 0; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0 
 }
}
```

Comment: also add a background color of white to #printpage and z-index if you encounter some layering issues